# SQL command calls recursive stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server and I am calling it from an ASP.NET Core application using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. I keep getting an exception:

> Maximum stored procedure, function trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

I did not know what this meant, so I looked it up and saw similar posts but all that I could gather was that I most likely have some sort of recursion happening in my stored procedure. In this stored procedure there is nothing but an `INSERT` statement that gets executed 32 times instead of only once.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addToTable]
    (@title nvarchar(100), @genre int)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Books] (Title, GenreId)
    VALUES (@title, @genre)
END

BEGIN
    EXEC addToTable @title, @genre
END
```

The C# call is pretty simple.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.addToTable", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "string value";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@genre", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 5;

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //Exception happens here
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint and step through the code, the exception happens on `ExecuteNonQuery()` and I can only assume it is because of something in the procedure.

Comment: You shouldn't have that EXEC command at the end. Remove that.

Comment: The stored procedure is the whole batch. So you must put `GO` between that and executing the procedure, to break it into a second batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have that EXEC command at the end. Remove that. What's happening here is that you are declaring a stored procedure, then executing it in the definition. So basically every time you call the stored procedure, it calls itself.

Just do this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addToTable]
    (@title nvarchar(100), @genre int)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Books] (Title, GenreId)
    VALUES (@title, @genre)
END

--Delete the following
--BEGIN
--EXEC addToTable @title, @genre
--END
```

Comment: My concern is, what if someone else creates the stored procedure on the db, and they add an exec statement? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: No. There's no way to avoid part of the stored procedure with C# code. You have to modify the stored procedure itself.